# Finding $\frac{\cos(x-z)}{\cos(w-y)}$ if $11\sin x+7\sin y=3(\sin z+3\sin w)$ and $11\cos x+7\cos y=3(\cos z+3\cos w)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So I was given this question:

> $$11\sin x+7\sin y =3(\sin z+3\sin w)$$
> $$11\cos x+7\cos y=3(\cos z +3\cos w)$$
> Find $\dfrac{\cos(x-z)}{\cos(w-y)}$.

I tried squaring the equations and adding them, but there were too many variables. Could someone give me an insight on how to approach this?

Comment: please use mathjax and fomulate your question better(seperate the question and your attempt  say into two parts).It makes reading much nicer

Comment: [MathJax Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, moving some parts, squaring and adding equations will lead to:
$$121-66(\sin x \sin z+\cos x\cos z)+9=81-112(\sin w \sin y+\cos w\cos y)+49$$ or 
$$130-66 \cos (x-z)=130-112 \cos (w-y)$$ Can you finish?